# "Unexpected Machine Code" warning from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

After I uploaded my build to iTunes Connect by using Application Loader, I got an email about an issue "Unexpected Machine Code" see below.

> Unexpected Machine Code - Your upload contains both bitcode and native
>   machine code. When you provide bitcode, it's not necessary to include
>   machine code as well. To reduce the size of your upload, use Xcode 7.3
>   or later, or any other toolchain that removes machine code.

I am so confused about this warning. Is this a new thing in iTunes Connect? Why it doesn't give me the warning when I upload QA build but Release build?

Update: I upload QA build last week, it wasn't any warning. And today (June 27th 2016) I upload Release build, it send me the warning.

Comment: I actually just got the same error. No clue why though as nothing in our code related to what I think this would be related to has changed. Are you by chance using Buddy Build?

Comment: @crewshin I am using Bitrise.io

Comment: @herbert - Just got this too a moment ago, never seen it before. I bet it's a bug. Don't know why you're getting down voted and people voting to close.

Comment: I received this email too today. We had an app update go through review two days ago without problems. And I uploaded a TestFlight internal build today that "processed" just fine. The thing that was odd to me was that all of the emails associated with our developer account were cc'd on the email. I called Apple Developer Support - no help there yet. The email I received arrived just before a TestFlight processing complete email arrived. I just did a "normal" Xcode build. No fancy build tools.

Comment: Just got this as well. Built from fastlane.

Comment: Same error. Built and uploaded directly from Xcode.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, I assume we can ignore this issue for now........ obviously the issue isn't at our side.

Comment: 20 min after getting this email, my app became available for testing. Seems likely it was a bug on Apple's end and it resolved itself.

Comment: I am nominating this question to be reopened. It is still occurring, and is not a simple typographical error. The question clearly explains the process used to reproduce the error, the error message (from Apple), and the expected result (no error).

Comment: Apparently this question should be reopened. And here is some update, I submitted my app for review (nothing changed after got the warning email) yesterday, and it passed today without any issue. I believe we can ignore the warning email and wait Apple's explanation.

Comment: How can I disable this email, for my internal testers?? I really don't want to annoy them with Apple's nonsense.

Comment: I got this issue today!! This question is so relevant!!

Comment: How is this off topic? It is still happening.

Comment: Yea, I've also had this happen to me today. However it's been over an hour and I don't see the build processing in itunes connect...

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Just got this as well, it's a bug. I uploaded the near exact same binary as I did a couple of days ago which went through fine (only change was to the version and build number). Developer support confirmed this.

If you do get the e-mail, don't worry about it. Your binary will still process and you'll still be able to submit it to the app store.

Update: both of my binaries which received this message passed review and have been released to the app store.

Comment: I hope you're correct. Do you have anything that indicates that this is a bug, rather than a new iTunesConnect validation?

Comment: @picciano I called up developer support and they said the same.

Comment: "I'm having this problem too" is not an answer.  Please use answers only for posts which answer the question.

Comment: @jal I updated my answer to include the tid bit about developer technical support

Comment: And.... what was the fix?  Did you upload a new binary?  Did they fix it?

Comment: @crankharder didn't need to, the binary went through just fine. The e-mail just served as a warning I guess? (a false one).

Comment: @SerPounce i too got the same email. Can you post a screenshot of the confirmation from the Developer technical support

Comment: I had this email come through. My build finished processing without any issues on the iTunes Connect side but I cannot select it to test in TestFlight Internal Testing settings...

Comment: @jakedunc I was able to push a build through Testflight in spite of getting this email.

Comment: Can anyone post screen shot of where apple is saying it's a mistake

Comment: @AdityaKorde - I called them. I misspoke when I said DTS, I meant the support line you can call, I believe it's worldwide developer support or something? Anyway, I'm working on getting the clarification in writing. Will report back when I do.

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar working on getting written proof, but they told me on the phone it was a bug.

Comment: Now I have 30 people in my company, most of them non-programmers, asking me what is that email. They are Testflight internal users, but they really just want to preview the apps. This is SO annoying!! I have 3 words for apple: shame.... shame... shame..! (bling! bling!)

Comment: How can I disable this email, for my internal testers?? I really don't want to annoy them with Apple's nonsense.

Comment: Submitted a binary for an Ionic app today (6/29) and got the same e-mail. However, it looks like the build got uploaded to iTunes Connect without any problems, it's processing now.

Comment: Has anyone successfully submitted their app to the stores and passed review?

Comment: @AndroidNoob Yes, both apps I submitted passed.

Comment: yes apps got submitted, the email states that it's a suggestion and we want so it's optional i ignored it.