# Cordova: Unexpected Machine Code - Your upload contains both bitcode and native machine code

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building an iOS Cordova app. And when I upload it to the iTunes Connect it returns the following error.

> Unexpected Machine Code - Your upload contains both bitcode and native machine code. When you provide bitcode, it's not necessary to include machine code as well. To reduce the size of your upload, use Xcode 7.3 or later, or any other toolchain that removes machine code.

I've changed quite a lot of settings in `config.xml` today so I'm not sure whether I've did something wrong and is it some kind of a new iTunes Connect thing.

As I understand it's quite easy to fix it changing some settings in Xcode, but I would like to avoid touching Xcode — is there any way to fix it using the `config.xml`?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Well, it seems to be an Apple issue — I was able to submit a build with such a warning to the TestFlight, actually test it through the TestFlight and submit it to the AppStore. It hasn't passed the Apple review yet, but I believe it will be ok, as typically, in the case of any real problems with the binary the build is rejected immediately.

**UPDATE 2**

The app with such a warning (actually 3 apps) has actually passed the AppStore review and went on sale. So I believe the issue can be safely ignored.

Comment: Interesting I'm running into this issue as well with XCode 7.3 and Cordova.  Let me know if you find a resolution.

Comment: In XCode 7.3, you can go to Build Settings > Search Bar > Type "Enable Bitcode" > No.  Do this for both the Project and the Target.

Comment: I just got this as well and my "Enable Bitcode" is already set to No on the Project and Target. I'm not sure this is related. I never got this until today. No major changes to project (just underlying JavaScript app) so I am thinking this is an Apple change.... Come to think of it, I did a "cordova build ios" before I submitted, maybe that generated some bit code. Perhaps only "cordova prepare iOS" is safe now...will test and report back.

Comment: I uploaded a build from Appcelerator this morning and didn't get this message. I just uploaded another build tonight, literally only changing 1 line of code in my app and I got this message. I'm assuming it's an error? My upload contained no Bitcode.

Comment: @TimPerry yeah i still got the same issue even with Enable Bitcode set to NO for both the Project and Target.  There's another thread on the apple forums where people are also facing the same issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50328

Comment: Just uploaded a build and had this email too. Bitcode is disabled. As far as I can tell I'm only using a binary library and some libraries included as source code. Never had this email before. The build was successfully processed and I pushed it to internal TestFlight successfully.

Comment: Same for me - but with a xamarin Project. so it's very likly this is an Apple issue

Comment: Same issue for me. Bitcode is disabled for both project and target. No extensions.

Comment: This is the bug.
Please look here: [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061045/unexpected-machine-code-warning-from-itunes-connect?rq=1)

Comment: Same here... I do have many frameworks and 3rd party libraries, but for 6 months never had an issue. Bitcode is already set to NO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posting an answer myself, as it seems to be quite a popular question with nobody answering — so the issue is on the Apple side. Some people contacted Apple support and confirmed this. There is no need to recompile anything. The binary with such a warning can be submitted to the AppStore — it will pass the review successfully. I've already did it with a few apps.

Check more details here: ["Unexpected Machine Code" warning from iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061045/unexpected-machine-code-warning-from-itunes-connect)

Answer (score 3):

I've found this thread:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50328

suggesting to set **Enable Bitcode** to **NO** 
but in my case it already was on NO and still got this message... :-\

however, another guy said:

> "It's happening to me as well. On stack overflow someone's says they
>   called iTC and it's a problem on their side."

so I hope it has no effect, and it'll gone as it appeared...

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same mail and, it's a bug, 
 [image]

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38061592/3626659

Comment: Not sure that rebuilding again will help, I work on a series of apps with the same codebase, so we build and upload dozens of them each day — all have the same warning now.

Comment: Rebuilding won't help.

Comment: ahh guys I didn't see this question is related to cordova and I answerd, but we all got that same mail I think :)

Answer (score 0):

I talked with the Apple Developer Support, the official one. They don't said it clearly, but yes it's a bug. So, it's confirmed that there's some malfunctioning in their side.

UPDATE: It won't affect the Apps in Production neither Testing!