# Unexpected Machine Code - Will this affect app approval?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

This is quite linked to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062907/cordova-unexpected-machine-code-your-upload-contains-both-bitcode-and-native) question but it doesn't have any solution.
On uploading a build to iTunes Connect, I received the following message:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Hurdal IL". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct
>   the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Unexpected Machine Code - Your upload contains both bitcode and native
>   machine code. When you provide bitcode, it's not necessary to include
>   machine code as well. To reduce the size of your upload, use Xcode 7.3
>   or later, or any other toolchain that removes machine code.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

1. What is the resolution?
2. Will the app approval be affected if this build is uploaded ?

Comment: I just got the same issue.

Comment: This is the bug. Please look here: [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061045/unexpected-machine-code-warning-from-itunes-connect?rq=1)

Comment: Have you used the Application Loader or you've uploaded from Xcode?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062907/cordova-unexpected-machine-code-your-upload-contains-both-bitcode-and-native

Comment: @Pravat-MujahMaskey : This question too was asked yesterday. So technically it should be a duplicate of my question :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just talked with the Apple Developer Support, the official one. They don't said it clearly, but yes it's a bug.
So, it's confirmed that there's some malfunctioning in their side.

UPDATE: It won't affect the Apps in Production neither Testing!

Comment: What did they actually say?

Comment: Talking sideways, yyeeeaaahhhh we heard about it, we are working on it... (working, never uttered fixing) it won't affect your apps. etc....

Comment: @HelenWood : You were right. And my app just got approved :) Check my answer.

Comment: I told you guys, just dismiss it... Still, that email to everybody is weird... Also CC are plain text emails, awful.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue but in my case I set in Xcode Build Setting Enable Bitcode to NO. After this error I change it to YES and it works

Answer (score 1):

No, its not effect app approval and the binary seems to be accepted by the iTunes store.

Comment: What about 1: `What is the resolution?`

Comment: If with resolution you mean fix/solution you most likely will have to wait for Apple to fix the bug on their side. They already confirmed that this behaviour is a bug.

Comment: Malte Köhrer, could you please share a link to where you saw the statement from Apple about this?

Comment: Ok, it is in linked topic. They "called developer support and they confirmed...".

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded a binary recently (like 20m ago). They did sent me a note just like you. After that, I just re-built it again, only update the build version (1943) and upload. Now it seems like there's nothing happened anymore. And the previous build (1942) has completed processing without failure. So I doubt it's a bug from Apple.

Just ignore it. You may want to build another binary to fix the warning tho.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem, I send my application to review with that issue.

**Result:**

My app pass the review and already in publication. No problem... I think it's a issue from iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

The app which I published with this waring **was just approved by Apple**. So to answer my question, **this won't affect the app approval**.
Also, I am accepting @Helen Wood's answer as she was right that this is an apple bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this as well, it's a bug. I uploaded the near exact same binary as I did a couple of days ago which went through fine (only change was to the version and build number). Developer support confirmed this.

If you do get the e-mail, don't worry about it. Your binary will still process and you'll still be able to submit it to the app store.